# Hidden tabs cannot be looked up

Tags: apex, visualforce

Any tab that is not shown cannot be looked up in a lookup relationship. Is there anyway to change this? If the custom object doesn't have a tab it works. If it has a hidden tab it is blank.

Comment: Are you sure this is due to tab settings? I have never seen that before (and cannot replicate either). Please check your object security settings as well. One thing that tab visibility does influence is search results. As an alternative, you could mark the tab 'Default Off' instead of 'Hidden'.